# how to tag and find objects using wireless technology

Tags: wireless

I am not sure if this is the right forum for this question, If not please help me move it to the right place :)

Question: I have 10-20 items like tables / books in a room and I want to put a small self powered chip on them (solar / battery) that i can use to track their position from another room (say 100-150 ft away), Is there any such module out there that i can use.

Like for instance say bluetooth / IR, I can have a tiny bluetooth / IR module attached to them and use my phone / Laptop to track / ping them. (bluetooth is for data transfer, all i want is like a homing beacon that just points its location)

If pointing location is a problem then it should just buzz it / turn an alarm when i try to locate it...

The key focus points are:

1) Size (smaller the better)

2) Power requirement (if can be powered by a button cell that can last say 6 months)

3) Cost (cheaper the better)

Thanks.

Comment: I am also searching for same thing ...so are you using RFID....I have also posted a similar Q here http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/51706/technology-to-search-small-objects-like-pendrive-key-chains-etc

Comment: @DextOr Yeah RDIF is the closest thing available for such requirement. The only problem is that the RFID tags are small and there are few that can be detected over 300ft through concrete walls and stuff but their scanners are comparatively big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use RFID technologies.

Tags are very low cost. But the reader could be expensive. Especially the ones that are able to read tags at several meters.