# technology to search small objects like pendrive, key-chains etc

Tags: sensor, transistors, amplifier, wireless, sound

I am a web developer by profession. few days back I lost 8gb pen-drive :(  I don't it is in home or somewhere else.... So now I am thinking of a device which can be attached with small objects so that their location can be detected ...like

Clap of sound 
Amplitude modulator transmitter attached to pen drive which can transmit special signals
Or any Bluetooth detector ....which can be used from mobile to detect

any thing I don't know

It should be effective , energy efficient and small

Can you suggest any thing :/

I was searching for sound and AM transmitter ....

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't seem to be asking about a particular EE concept or problem. Product R&D is a little out of scope. See http://electronics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions

Comment: @JYelton I found a similer question here  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/50772/how-to-tag-and-find-objects-using-wireless-technology

Comment: Just advising that you may get better mileage with more specifics. :)

Comment: Attach it to a spare car tire with a piece of string ;o)

Comment: Is what you want any different from the various keyfinders that you can buy? Me private solution is to 'chain' my pendrive to my briefcase. A bit inconvenient at times, but I never lost a keydrive again.

Comment: Dude, you took my name. :D

Comment: @dext0rb HAHAHAHAH  what does "b" mean at end ;O  |O|  ;D

Comment: The "b" stands for bargain! http://images1.fanpop.com/images/quiz/3780_1212505215719_319_213.jpg

Answer (score 2):

There are a few commercial devices to find lost remotes, keys, and other small items. They usually work by having a small radio frequency (RF) receiver that uses a button cell and attaches to the item intended to be found. (It's similar to a keyless entry fob for your vehicle.)

When the item goes missing, the user presses a button on a base station (or sometimes another remote-size thing; which I suppose could also get lost, but that's another subject...). When the receiver picks up the signal, it emits a beep and/or flashes a light, etc.

Bluetooth is only designed for about 10 meter (30 ft) range, but [higher power Bluetooth devices could have ranges up to 100 meters (300 ft)](http://www.mobileinfo.com/Bluetooth/FAQ.htm#t6).

Some commercial products that are similar to your need:

- [KeyRinger](http://www.keyringer.com/)
- [Click N' Dig](http://clickndig.com/)

And a discussion about a device that might respond to sound instead of RF:

> http://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/showthread.php?t=41323

Answer (score 1):

I have also looked around for something that can do this. The best bet is RFID.

Look for a 3-10 GHz microwave frequency RFID tags that can be detected over 200 meters. (~600 ft).

These tags are very small (some come as transparent) the only problem is the tag readers. The higher you go on frequency / accuracy the more bulky and expensive these readers get and unfortunately there is no small tag like reader available out there.

Do post back if you get any better solution :)

Comment: I think a keychain which makes sound in response to clap or high pitch sound will also work.... Do you have any idea about construction of tags of RFID /RDIF whatever ;>

Comment: Hey see this http://www.indiegogo.com/sticknfind ... very sad this was ours idea ;/  but now I know it is possible .... ;)